# VS Code как задать игнорирование файлов при форматировании (Beautify)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, include

Использую gulp с плагином include. Чтобы подключить файлы нужно написать @@include. При форматировании Джава скрипта это изменяется на @ @include, что приводит к ошибке. Можно ли как-то настроить, чтобы или эта строчка не форматировалась, или весь js файл. Просто хочется оставить форматирование при сохранении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы исключить js/jsx файлы измените в settings.json

```
"beautify.ignore": ["**/*.js", "**/*.jsx"]
```